# Laravel/Blade, template content within content

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an array that I store the definition of a "notification". Two of these have dynamic variables that I want to template, but the content itself is also a template.

```
'start_process_import' => array(
    "content" => "Started processing: {{$name}}",
    "view" => '/ajax_templates/notifications/notification',
    'icon' => 'fa-plus',
    'labelStyle' => 'label-success',
    'href' => '/user/view/{{$id}}'
)
```

As you can see, the "content" and "href" index both have Blade templated content within it.

I then pass this data, plus other data to a rendered view like so:

```
$response['content'] = view($configView['view'], $data)->render());
```

And here is the views template file, which does properly get blade templated.

```
       <li>
<a href="{{ $href }}">
    <span class="time">{{ $date }}</span>
    <span class="details">                                                       
        <span class="label label-sm label-icon {{ $labelStyle }}">
            <i class="fa {{$icon}}"></i>
        </span>
        {{$content}} 
    </span>
</a>
```

Here is the output:

```
       <li>
<a href="/user/view/{{$id}}">
    <span class="time">2016-09-18 11:37:37</span>
    <span class="details">                                                       
        <span class="label label-sm label-icon label-success">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </span>
        Started processing: {{$name}} 
    </span>
</a>
```

The $id and $name variables are still lingering and are not being Blade template formatted.

Is there a way to "double" blade template the view?

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the variables: `$name` and `$id` within the Templates, right? A Suggestion would be offered below, which may be useful. However, there is no way of knowing if it works or not. Here is the Suggestion:

```
<?php

    'start_process_import' => array(
        "content" => "Started processing: ",     //<== REMOVED DYNAMIC VARIABLE: $name
        "view" => '/ajax_templates/notifications/notification',
        'icon' => 'fa-plus',
        'labelStyle' => 'label-success',
        'href' => '/user/view/'                 //<==  REMOVED DYNAMIC VARIABLE: $id
    );
```

**BLADE TEMPLATE**

```
   <li>
       <!-- SINCE BOTH $id & $name ARE AVAILABLE TO YOU IN THE CURRENT TEMPLATE -->
       <!-- YOU COULD STRIP THE DYNAMIC VARIABLES($name & $id) FROM THE content & href KEYS -->
       <!-- AND PERHAPS ADD THEM DIRECTLY HERE WITHIN THE TEMPLATE -->
        <a href="{{ $href }}{{ $id }}">
            <span class="time">{{ $date }}</span>
            <span class="details">                                                       
                <span class="label label-sm label-icon {{ $labelStyle }}">
                    <i class="fa {{$icon}}"></i>
                </span>
                {{ $content }}{{ $name }}
            </span>
        </a>
   </li>
```

Comment: Some content will not have "$id" set for the other template and some will.

Comment: 'subscription_complete' => array(
        "content" => "Signed up for {{$package->name}} package!",
        "view" => '/ajax_templates/notifications/notification',
        'icon' => 'fa-ticket',
        'labelStyle' => 'label-success',
        'href' => '/user/billing/info'
    )

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to re-render template twice, you need to use [String Blade Compiler](https://github.com/TerrePorter/StringBladeCompiler) package or similar one.